# How can the result of the input from the cycle be saved to the object?

Tags: javascript, prompt

How to change cycle, that input will be saved in object like this:

```
expenses: {
    “Item name[1]” : “Item price[1]”,
    “Item name[2]” : “Item price[2]”
}
```

Here is the code:

```
let appData = {
    expenses: {},
    value: 0,
    askExpenses: {},
    asking: function() {
        for (let i=0; i < 2; i++) {
            appData.askExpenses[i] = prompt('item name');
            appData.value[i] = +prompt('item value');
            }
    }
};
appData.asking();
```

Comment: ur asking the user to input data(in a very specific way).. don't u see the obvious error down the road?

Comment: I dont like this way too, but according of the task, it is necessary to place the cycle inside the function 'asking'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the title as the key by wrapping the variable in brackets.

```js
let appData = {
  expenses: {},
  value: 0,
  askExpenses: {},
  asking: function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      title = prompt('item name');
      value = +prompt('item value');
      appData.expenses[[title]] = value;
    }
  }
};
appData.asking();

console.log(appData.expenses);
```

Comment: appData.expenses[[title]] = value;

I change it a litlle bit and now all works fine. Thank you. 

appData.expenses[appData.askExpenses[i]] = appData.value[i];